# why I cannot find explicit finite difference for elliptic equation

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, differential-equations

Let us think on the Poisson equation $\nabla^2 u(\bf{x})=\rho(x)$ with Neumann boundary conditions, with $\bf{x}=\it (x,y)$ in 2D.

Here is a stencil with central differences in both $x$ and $y$ (forgive my label $t$ on the vertical, it is supposed to be $y$)  directions.
[image]

with $\beta=\Delta x/\Delta y$. More specifically we have the
equation:

\begin{eqnarray*}
  w_{i+1 j} -2 w_{ij} \left (  1 + \beta^2 \right)
  + w_{i-1 j} + \beta^2 (w_{i j+1} + w_{i j-1})
  = \Delta x^2 \rho(x,y)
\end{eqnarray*}

We can get a similar stencil in the (hyerbolic) wave equation in 1D where
time is the $y$ (vertical axis). We can always find, recursively 
$w_{i j+1}$ in terms of all other $w_{lm}$ where $l=i,i+1,i-1$ and
$m=j,j-1$. The points 1 cell away from the boundary can be computed with
a ghost boundary condition (assuming Neumann BC with derivative equal to 0).

I have been searching for hours and all literature shows me an implicit method where I need to invert a huge $(n-1 \times m-1)$ matrix. Is there a specific reason why the elliptic equation is not solved as we do the 1D wave explicit solution centered in space and time?

Or...if it could be solved, is there a place to look for that solution? Thanks.

Comment: Others might be able to provide some deeper insight, but generally the nature of Poisson's problem is such that the values of the solution at all grid points cannot be decoupled. For example, if you change the right-hand side $\rho$ in some area of your domain, it will affect the value of $u$ everywhere. This distinguishes it from the wave equation, where some initial data is propagated with finite speed.

Comment: Explicit methods are for problems with time dependence.  The elliptic equation has no time dependence.

Comment: @Paul : This is the point. The time independent problems call for implicit implementations. Why?  Is this due to what cthl  indicates above? Thanks.

Comment: Time and space are fundamentally different for the problems that you mentioned. When solving the wave equation for some time interval $(0,T)$, information about the wave at times $t\le t_0\in (0,T)$ is sufficient to predict its behavior at time $t_0$. It does not depend on future events. However, when solving Poisson's problem on an interval $(0,L)$ (in space), the solution at $x_0\in(0,L)$ *does* depend on information for $x>x_0$, e.g., the values of $\rho$.

Comment: @cthl :  I guess I follow you. Causality is a time dependence issue. Thanks.

Comment: You can use Jacobi method. I would say that in that case you have an explicit method.